# Dynamically connect circles with lines D3 Javascript SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to connect circles from left to right and from right to left with lines.  but I havent been able to make the line stick on the targeted circle.
The lines just stick on random circles if not the same one. 
cD is Right circle ;
cG is Left circle ;
cS is source circle, meaning the circle that the line came from

What I've dabbled on the "mousemove" function is what made some progress. I was thinking, if the mouse is on any circle that is not the source circle, the X2,y2 of the line should take the cx,cy which are the center of the circle. But that would also make the lines stick to circles of the same color as you can see in the screenshot.

[image: Here's a screenshot of where I'm at.]

Here's the rendering code:

```
function setPoints(){
    //ajoute les points
    svgContainer = d3.select("#centre").append("svg")
        .attr("id", "svgGlobal")
        .attr("width", "100%")
        .attr("height", "100%")
        .on("mouseup", mouseupVide);
    //récupère les cordonnées du svg
    var rectSVG = document.getElementById("svgGlobal").getBoundingClientRect();      
    //ajoute les points à droites
    var circlesDroite = svgContainer.selectAll(".cD")
        .data(dataset.droite)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "cD")
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
            return rectSVG.width - r; 
            })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            var rect = document.getElementById(d).getBoundingClientRect();
            return rect.top-rectSVG.top+(rect.height/2); 
             })
        .attr("r", r)
        .on("mousedown", mousedown)         
        .on("mouseup", mouseup)     
        .on("mouseover", mouseoverCircle)       
        .on("mouseout", mouseoutCircle)     
        ;//.style("fill", "red");       
    //ajoute les points à gauche
    var circlesGauche = svgContainer.selectAll(".cG")
        .data(dataset.gauche)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "cG")
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
            return r; 
            })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            var rect = document.getElementById(d).getBoundingClientRect();
            return rect.top-rectSVG.top+(rect.height/2); 
             })
        .attr("r", r)
        .on("mousedown", mousedown)         
        .on("mouseup", mouseup)     
        .on("mouseover", mouseoverCircle)       
        .on("mouseout", mouseoutCircle)     
        ;//.style("fill", "green");             
}
```

And these are he mouse functions

```
function mousedown() 
{
    var m = d3.mouse(this);
    var c = d3.select(this);
    c.attr("class", "cS");
    line = svgContainer.append("line")
        .attr("x1", c.attr("cx"))
        .attr("y1",c.attr("cy"))
        .attr("x2", m[0])
        .attr("y2", m[1]);
    lineEnd = false;
    svgContainer.on("mousemove", mousemove);
}

function mousemove() {
   var m = d3.mouse(this);
    var c = d3.select(this);
        line.attr("x2", m[0]);
        line.attr("y2", m[1]);

    if(d3.select(this).attr("class") == "cS") {
        line.attr("x2", m[0]);
        line.attr("y2", m[1]);
    } else {
        line.attr("x2", d3.select(this).attr("cx"));
        line.attr("y2", d3.select(this).attr("cy"));
    }
}

function mouseup() {
    var m = d3.mouse(this);
    var c = d3.select(this);

    //c.attr("r", r*2);
    if (lineEnd==true){
        if (Math.sqrt((m[0]-c[0])*(m[0]-c[0]) + (m[1]-c[1])*(m[1]-c[1])) < c.attr("r")){
            line.attr("x2", c[0])
            .attr("y2", c[1]);
        }
    }     
}   

function mouseupVide() {
    if(!lineEnd)line.remove();
    else lineEnd = false;       
    svgContainer.on("mousemove", null);
}   

function mouseoverCircle(){
    var c = d3.select(this);
    c.attr("class", "cS");
    //console.log(c.attr("r")); 
    lineEnd = true;  
}

function mouseoutCircle(d){
    var c = d3.select(this);

    if(d.substr(0,3)=='acd')
        c.attr("class", "cD");
    else
         c.attr("class", "cG");
    lineEnd = false;        
}
```

Comment: could you show your rendering code? (the svg or html you use to draw the circles)

Comment: A scaled down version in jsfiddle would be convenient

Comment: @martinjakubik I just added it above

Comment: This is a good question but from your code above it's difficult to isolate your problem. You will have a better chance of help here if you break the problem into smaller pieces. Then, ask one small question at a time.